# How to autoremove dependent Python packages within a pipenv when uninstalling a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, uninstallation, pipenv

When you use `pipenv` to install a package, all the dependent packages will also be installed with it. Uninstalling that package with `pipenv uninstall` will not remove the dependent packages automatically.

How to get the equivalent functionality of `pip-autoremove` within a pipenv?

For example:

```
$ cd testpipenv
$ pipenv install requests
$ pipenv shell
(testpipenv) $ pipenv graph

requests==2.24.0
 - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2020.6.20]
 - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<4, installed: 3.0.4]
 - idna [required: >=2.5,<3, installed: 2.10]
 - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.1,!=1.25.0, installed: 1.25.9]

(testpipenv) $ pipenv uninstall requests
(testpipenv) $ pip list

Package    Version
---------- ---------
certifi    2020.6.20
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.10
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 47.3.1
urllib3    1.25.9
wheel      0.34.2
```

The dependent packages of `requests`, such as `urllib3` are still installed which can be verified by

```
(testpipenv) $ python 
>>> import urllib3
```

This was also discussed here: [Pipenv uninstall doesn't uninstall dependencies - issue #1470](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1470), and I have not found a more current set of instructions in regards to autoremoval of packages with pipenv.

Versions used:

- pipenv, version 2020.5.28
- Python 3.6.10

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not apply to the question, in which I was asking specifically about doing the equivalent of `pip-autoremove` *within* a pipenv. Using pip commands or similar commands which do not take into account the pipenv is not really recommended. - The other command in the link `pipdeptree` is similar to `pipenv graph` in that it will show a dependency tree, but will not automatically remove unused packages.

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR

```
(testpipenv) $ pipenv uninstall requests && pipenv clean
```

---

To get similar functionality to `pip-autoremove` using just `pipenv`commands I did the following, continuing with the example above:

```
(testpipenv) $ pipenv graph
 
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
urllib3==1.25.9
```

This shows that the dependent packages are still installed, but these have already been removed form Pipfile.lock. Therefore, using `pipenv clean` will remove them:

```
(testpipenv) $ pipenv clean

Uninstalling certifi…
Uninstalling idna…
Uninstalling urllib3…
Uninstalling chardet…
```

In summary...

```
(testpipenv) $ pipenv uninstall requests && pipenv clean
```

... will remove all the dependent packages and is the closest equivalent to `pip-autoremove`.

This may be more aggressive than intended as the `clean` command 'Uninstalls all packages not specified in Pipfile.lock' If packages have not been added to Pipfile.lock before using clean, this command might remove more than intended. I do not know if this is really a concern, as `uninstall` automatically updates Pipfile.lock unless additional options such as `--skip-lock` are specified.

---

Another alternative would be...

```
pipenv --rm && pipenv install
```

... which will remove everything and rebuild the virtual environment based on Pipfile.lock. This would work but is slow as it deletes the full virtual environment and reinstalls everything, except for the unneeded dependencies.